# Limited internet connectivity when connected to WiFi and USB-HSPA/3G

Tags: wireless-networking, router, internet, printing

My setup is as follows:

1. An old Billion 400G router, not connected to the internet
2. A new D-Link USB-HSPA/3G internet stick

I need to connect to the router via WiFi to be able to print (I have a Canon 217w connected to the router via WiFi), as well as the internet stick for internet connectivity.

However, when both are connected, Windows indicates that there is limited connectivity on both connections - in other words, it doesn't pick up internet from the stick when the laptop is also connected to WiFi.

Not very clued up when it comes to networking, but I do know that DHCP is enabled. I have tried bridging the connections, but that results in a *very* slow internet connection from the stick.

So my question is this: how do I maintain both connections, and retain a high-speed internet connection?

Comment: The order of connections makes a difference, so you should clarify and possibly test it more to see what works when you connect wifi first or the other way around.

Comment: Hmm, seems interesting. The first time I connected to the stick first (it was on anyway), and then WiFi, and it claimed limited connectivity. Have just reconnected to both in the same order after deleting the bridge, and now it's working as expected, and speed looks fine... Seems quite strange.

Comment: And then it dropped... So I reconnected with WiFi first, then the stick. It first said Limited, and now it seems to be connected. Let's see if it holds.

Comment: The fact that the connection doesn't hold may most likely depend on the 3G connection's stability more than anything else.

Comment: It seems to be holding. 3G signal is top-notch, but we do get problems every now and then - so *may* have been a false-positive... Thanks for the hat-tip on precedence; have now read an article about how that works.

Comment: Please can you add your comment as an answer so I can accept it? Looks to be the correct answer, AFAIK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order of connections makes a difference.  On most systems, the connection order will have a direct effect on the computer's routing table, unless it is explicitly configured manually.

Comment: So a few minutes ago, I rebooted my laptop as part of an installation, and this no longer worked immediately. It took a few minutes for it to pick up where the internet is coming from, and now reconnecting in the reverse order works... How does one manually configure the routing table, or at least see what comes first?